# What's wrong with my proof of quotient rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, fake-proofs

I seem to have arrived at a contradiction by applying what I know about quotient rings. I can't figure out where the mistake is.

Let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, $\deg f(x)\ge 1$, and $p$ a prime number. Then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}[x]/f(x)\mathbb{Z}[x]&\cong (\mathbb{Z}[x]/p\mathbb{Z}[x])/((f(x)\mathbb{Z}[x])/p\mathbb{Z}[x])\tag{Third Iso. Thm}\\
&\cong(\mathbb{Z}[x]/p\mathbb{Z}[x])/(\hat{f}(x)(\mathbb{Z}[x]/p\mathbb{Z}[x]))\tag{$*$}\\
&\cong \mathbb{Z}_p[x]/\hat{f}(x)\mathbb{Z}_p[x].
\end{align*}

where $(*)$ comes from:

\begin{align*}
(f(x)\mathbb{Z}[x])/p\mathbb{Z}[x]&=\{g(x)+p\mathbb{Z}[x]:g(x)\in f(x)\mathbb{Z}[x]\}\\
&=\{f(x)g(x)+p\mathbb{Z}[x]:g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]\}\\
&=\{(f(x)+p\mathbb{Z}[x])(g(x)+p\mathbb{Z}[x]):g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]\}\\
&=\{\hat{f}(x)(g(x)+p\mathbb{Z}[x]):g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]\}\\
&=\hat{f}(x)(\mathbb{Z}[x]/p\mathbb{Z}[x])
\end{align*}

For example, this would seem to show that $$\mathbb{Z}[i]\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)\mathbb{Z}[x]\cong \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^2+1)\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$$ The first ring is infinite and the last ring is finite. What's going on here?

Comment: The problem is that $(\Bbb Z[x])/(p\Bbb Z[x])$ is not equal to $(\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z)[x]$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Are you sure about that? Could you prove it in an answer form?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If you define $f:\mathbb{Z}[x]\to \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ by modding the coefficients by $p$, then isn't $\text{Ker}(f)$ just $p\mathbb{Z}[x]$, proving the desired isomorphism?

Comment: @Riley An element in the ring $\;\left(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\right)[x]\;$ is a polynomial, whereas an element in the ring $\;\Bbb Z[x]/p\Bbb Z[x]\;$ is **not** a polynomial but in fact an equivalence class...

Comment: Are you talking of *equality* or *isomorphic*? All this is confusing as Omnomnomnom wrote "not equal" ...

Comment: @DonAntonio 1. But the equivalence classes are precisely the elements of the quotient ring. So doesn't that make $\hat{f}$ a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$? 2. I believe showing they are isomorphic is sufficient for my "proof".

Comment: Whatever you meant, the very first equality (isomorphism) is wrong **unless** $\;p\Bbb Z[x]\subset f(x)\Bbb Z[x]\;$ , as required by the third isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah, that's it. I'll accept that if you put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you meant, the very first equality (isomorphism) is wrong unless $\;p\Bbb Z[x]⊂f(x)\Bbb Z[x]\;$ , as required by the third isomorphism theorem